# How to play audio files at phone volume level, not speaker volume

Tags: android

I'm writing an Android application that plays back voice mails using MediaPlayer, which are just WAV files that have been sent to the device.  When I play the file, it's played on the device's speaker, or else it plays through headphones if they're plugged in.

What I want to do is play the file so that it sounds to the user as if it's at the same volume level as a normal phone call.  Is there a way to route playback so that the file is played through the phone's earpiece instead of out of the speaker?

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`MediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setAudioStreamType%28int%29) to set the playback stream to [`AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_VOICE_CALL).

Comment: I say 'try' because I have no idea whether this is the solution or not. :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to use the `AudioManager` class:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html

`setSpeakerphoneOn(false)` is what you need to call to route the audio to the earpiece.

**Edit:**  except is doesn't seem to actually have any effect on anything.  That's irritating.